# java swing GroupLayout - Howto exchange position of components

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, grouplayout

I have a JFrame layouted in GroupLayout. I would like to exchange the position of two components in this JFrame when user clicks a button. I used the method `replace()` in GroupLayout to replace one with the other. Here's the code that I want to exchange the position of two buttons : `buttons[0]` and `buttons[1]`:

```
groupLayout.replace(buttons[1], buttons[2]);
groupLayout.replace(buttons[2], buttons[1]);
```

However, the program thorws `NullPointerException` when I run this. The exception does not provide any helpful information:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.swing.GroupLayout$ComponentInfo.setBounds(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.GroupLayout.layoutContainer(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.layout(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.doLayout(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.validate(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.validateInvalidComponents(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

(At first, I thought it was because buttons[2] has already been removed. But when I tried  `replace(buttons[1],buttons[3])` where buttons[3] was not added to groupLayout before, nothing went wrong. So I still could not figure what problem had happened.)

Then, I came up with an idea of maintain an reference to the Group which contains only the the component that I want to change so as to manipulate it later. Here's my code:

```
if(count % 2 == 1) {
    groupLayout.replace(buttons[1], buttons[2]);
    button2HorizontalGroup.addComponent(buttons[1]);
    button2VerticalGroup.addComponent(buttons[1]);
}else {
    groupLayout.replace(buttons[2], buttons[1]);
    button2HorizontalGroup.addComponent(buttons[2]);
    button2VerticalGroup.addComponent(buttons[2]);
}
```

But this may be more a hack than a solution. Plus, it could be cumbersome if one were to exchange large amounts of components. Is there any better solution to exchange components in GroupLayout? (Solutions in other layouts are also welcome :) )

Thanks.

---

**Update:**

@user1803551:
Here's my Code (GroupLayoutTest is a class which extends JFrame):

```
public GroupLayoutTest() {
    // Allow group layout to automatically creat the gap between components and containers.
    groupLayout.setAutoCreateGaps(true);
    groupLayout.setAutoCreateContainerGaps(true);
    setLayout(groupLayout);


    buttons = new JButton[4];
    buttons[0] = new JButton("small 1");
    buttons[1] = new JButton("medium 2");
    buttons[2] = new JButton("big 3");

    buttons[1].addActionListener(replaceHandler);
    buttons[2].addActionListener(replaceHandler);

    button1HorizontalGroup.addComponent(buttons[1]);
    button1VerticalGroup.addComponent(buttons[1]);
    button2HorizontalGroup.addComponent(buttons[2]);
    button2VerticalGroup.addComponent(buttons[2]);

    groupLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            groupLayout.createParallelGroup()
            .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(39)
                    .addComponent(buttons[0])
                    // Make it like a Spring
                    .addPreferredGap(LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addGap(10)
                    .addGroup(button1HorizontalGroup)
                    .addGap(52))
            .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addPreferredGap(LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addGap(0)
                    .addGroup(button2HorizontalGroup)
                    .addContainerGap(GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 160))
    );
    groupLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(50, 50)
            .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup()
                    .addComponent(buttons[0])
                    .addGroup(button1VerticalGroup) )
            .addGap(10)
            .addPreferredGap(LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(button2VerticalGroup)
            .addContainerGap(168, 168));

    groupLayout.linkSize(SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL, buttons[1],buttons[2]);
    pack();
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

private class ReplaceHandler implements ActionListener {

    private int count = 0;
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        count += 1;
        if(count % 2 == 1) {
            groupLayout.replace(buttons[1], buttons[2]);
            button2HorizontalGroup.addComponent(buttons[1]);
            button2VerticalGroup.addComponent(buttons[1]);
        }else {
            groupLayout.replace(buttons[2], buttons[1]);
            button2HorizontalGroup.addComponent(buttons[2]);
            button2VerticalGroup.addComponent(buttons[2]);
        }
        groupLayout.linkSize(SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL, buttons[1],buttons[2]);
    }

}
```

@camickr: As you can seen from above code, I'm just having fun with my first experience of GroupLayout. I'd like to have one buttons (the "medium" and the "small") exchange each other when I clicked it. After all, thanks for your advice. :)

Comment: Don't use a GroupLayout. That layout was designed to be used by IDE's and is not easy to code manually, expecially when doing dynamic changes. You will benefit more by learning to create GUI's manually and by not relying on an IDE.

Comment: @camickr I code with `GroupLayout` manually a lot, its complexity is overrated, just a matter of getting used to.

Comment: And to the point: you can exchange components' places in many layouts, what exactly do you have and what do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm just having fun with my first experience of GroupLayout.

Well, you should learn other layout managers first

> I'd like to have one buttons (the "medium" and the "small") exchange each other when I clicked it.

Create a JPanel to contain your two buttons and add the panel to the layout.

Make one button visible and the other button invisible. When you click on the button you then toggle the visibility states of both buttons.

Comment: **1.** Er, I have some difficulty using other components. It's always hard to make something fixed (especially the size) in most layout manager, isn't it. So I tryied grouplayout. **2.** Toggling the visibility of buttons does not change their position. Besides, my two buttons locate in two seperate position. It's hard to place them all inside one JPanel.

Comment: @we-taper, when you say "exchange with each other", it sounds to me like the two buttons occupy the same place, but only one is visible at a time which is why I made my suggestion. If the buttons are at different locations on the panel, then you should be able to toggle the visibility. Of course this assumes the GroupLayout does respect the visibility of a component.

Comment: Thanks for that. May I ask you why I have such a `NullPointerException` (in my first example)? There is no useful  information provided. I cannot even catch this Exception (I tried but failed).

Comment: I can't guess why you have a NPE base on a couple of lines of code. When you ask a question you should always include a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem. However, since I know nothing about the GroupLayout I won't be able to help.